# error with gatsby finding preset "react" when running gatsby develop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, command-line-interface, gatsby

I'm trying to get gatsby to make a new project and hopefully use it to power a new blog. So, I downloaded the cli, created a new project, cd into that folder, and tried to run 'gatsby develop', which results in an error I can't find the answer to. It says it can't find preset "react" in my root directory. Why is it looking for react in my root directory when the project folder isn't located there?

Here's what my terminal looks like:

```
 C:\Users\Kevin Murphy\Desktop\Projects\web-dev-blog  (gatsby-starter-default@1.0.0)
λ gatsby develop
success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.023 s
success open and validate gatsby-config.js — 0.005 s
success copy gatsby files — 0.022 s
success onPreBootstrap — 0.034 s
success source and transform nodes — 0.018 s
success building schema — 0.111 s
success createLayouts — 0.038 s
success createPages — 0.001 s
success createPagesStatefully — 0.035 s
success onPreExtractQueries — 0.000 s
success update schema — 0.042 s
success extract queries from components — 0.064 s
success run graphql queries — 0.027 s
success write out page data — 0.008 s
success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
success onPostBootstrap — 0.001 s

info bootstrap finished - 4.074 s

error There was an error compiling the html.js component for the development server.

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help 


  Error: Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "C:\\Users\\Kevi
  n Murphy"

  - option-manager.js:293
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19

  - Array.map

  - option-manager.js:275 OptionManager.resolvePresets
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20

  - option-manager.js:264 OptionManager.mergePresets
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10

  - option-manager.js:249 OptionManager.mergeOptions
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14

  - option-manager.js:368 OptionManager.init
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12

  - index.js:212 File.initOptions
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65

  - index.js:135 new File
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24

  - pipeline.js:46 Pipeline.transform
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-core]/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16

  - index.js:46 transpile
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-loader]/lib/index.js:46:20

  - fs-cache.js:79
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-loader]/lib/fs-cache.js:79:18

  - fs-cache.js:15 ReadFileContext.callback
    [web-dev-blog]/[babel-loader]/lib/fs-cache.js:15:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in one of your components or pages, you're importing react from `/react` instead of just `react`?  It should look like `import React from 'react'`.